# Android Exception Thrown After JSON Conversion (only on device)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json, android-emulator

I'm having an issue with an Android App that I've written, but it is only evident when I run it on my actual phone device.  It runs without issues in the emulator.  Here's the class where the problem happens:

```
public class JsonServiceHandler {
    private final static String QUEUE_SERVICE_URI = "http://192.168.1.132/QueueTest/AccessService.svc/JSON";

    public static <T extends QueueAccessObject> List<T> GetServiceResult(String serviceMethod, Class<T> classType, Hashtable parameters){
        try
        {
            String url = QUEUE_SERVICE_URI + "/" + serviceMethod;

            if(parameters != null && parameters.size() > 0)
            {
                url += "?";

                Enumeration e = parameters.keys();

                while(e.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    Object key = e.nextElement();
                    url += key.toString() + "=" + parameters.get(key);
                }
            }

            // Send GET request to <service>/<endpoint>
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

            JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
            JSONObject ridesResult = jsobj.getJSONObject(serviceMethod + "Result");

            List<T> array = GetObjectsFromJSONArray(ridesResult.getJSONArray("RootResults"), classType);

            return array;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static <T extends QueueAccessObject> List<T> GetObjectsFromJSONArray(JSONArray jArray, Class<T> classType) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        try
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); ++i){
                T item = classType.getConstructor(JSONObject.class).newInstance(jArray.getJSONObject(i));
                list.add(item);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}

        return list;                
    }

}
```

The problem is happening after I take the JSON result of an HttpGet and copy it over to an array of strongly typed objects.

When the exception is thrown, the JSON response looks fine, and the list of strongly typed objects appears to be created and returned just fine.  It only blows up on the assignment *after* the call to GetObjectsFromJSONArray `List<T> array = GetObjectsFromJSONArray(...`.

When it drops down the the catch block (4 lines afterward), the exception does not appear to be instantiated in Eclipse.

As I mentioned, I do not have this problem in the Android emulator, only when testing on my phone.  Also, the problem only occurs about 3 out of 4 times on the device itself, so it doesn't happen consistently.

FYI, this is all happening inside an AsyncTask, so there shouldn't be an issue with doing Async network calls on the UI thread.

I'm new to Android, and in fact new to Java and Eclipse, so I could easily be overlooking something simple.

Any ideas on what is happening or why my exception is not available in the catch block?

Comment: Does this code compile?  I'm asking because you are using some very confusing words "why my exception is not available in the catch block" and "the exception does not appear to be instantiated in Eclipse".  Your code also seems to be missing a closing brace, hence I wonder if you are talking about compile time or run time problems.

Comment: It does compile, and it installs and runs on both the emulator and my Android phone.  I don't see the missing closing brace, but if it's missing it's a copy/paste error.  The non-existence of an exception is pretty confusing to me too, but it's definitely happening at runtime, and I've definitely seen other exceptions instantiated in Eclipse where this one is has no instance available.

Comment: To clarify, I step over the "List<T> array = GetObjectsFromJSONArray(..." line (even after stepping all the way through the returned value from that method and seeing that the List<T> is populated and returned) the debug point is taken to the head of the Catch block below, and the exception, when I try to inspect it, has no instance available.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Only thing I can offer is to say I've seen something similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616518/why-does-this-boolean-method-use-the-wrong-return-path.  I never found an answer and ended up recoding the method.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm really interested in this.  If you do find a solution, please come back. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a real exception being thrown here, and I did finally get it to show. The issue that caused it to remain uninstantiated appears to be that the exception was never itself used in the Catch block (I was only returning a null). Maybe there's some type of compiler optimization for the Android environment such that the Exception parameter isn't created if it isn't used?

When I added code that actually uses the Exception itself instead of swallowing it, I got a JSONException telling me that my response is getting chopped off mid-stream.  Of course, now I have to figure out why that is happening (and only on the device), but the issue with the exception instantiation had to do with the fact that it was being trimmed out for lack of being used.

**Edit:**

Further information on the JSONException itself: Apparently the code that I was using to load in the HttpResponse into the JSONObject is ineffective, or at least inconsistently effective:

```
    // Read response data into buffer
    char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
    InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    reader.read(buffer);
    stream.close();

    JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
```

I've removed this code in preference of the contents of the convertStreamToString method found [here](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/).  That got me rolling.